# Tips for improving this PT100 sensor amplifier circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, noise

I'm designing a circuit to read a PT100 temperature sensor using an OP-amp and the ADC of a PIC 16F1788. I've designed the following circuit:

[image: Schematic]

The PT100 sensor is labelled PT100. The basic idea is a non-inverting OP-amp configuration with a gain of approximately 300, and an offset, such that signals of 100mV and 116mV are amplified to 0V and 5V respectively. This is to give the sensor a range of approximately 0 degree C to ~40 degree C, for sensing indoor temperatures. I've derived the exact formula for converting nominal ADC voltage to temperature, but I'll spare you the details in this question.

After the output of the OP-amp I've put a simple low-pass filter.

I've built this circuit on a PCB, but without the low pass filter, and then the total noise is equivalent to 0.5 degree C. This is approximateley 0.0625V at the ADC, and 195 microvolt at the OP-amp + input. I'm now spinning a new PCB, with space for the filter, and a lot of improvements unrelated to this question.

The circuit works, and using filtering in software I can sense very small temperature differences (such as a few 0.1 deg C from turning on a lamp a meter from the sensor). However I'd like to not have to do all this filtering in software.

Is the low-pass filter a reasonable precaution to getting lower noise? Am I right in thinking it is more effective from a noise perspective to put it at the ADC compared to trying to put it over the PT100?

Anything else that could be improved in this circuit (since I'm ordering a new PCB anyway)?

I've been thinking about putting a ~680 ohm resistor right after the voltage regulator, so that it together with C2 creates a low pass filter, and then to connect the ADC Vref+ of the PIC ADC to the positive terminal of C2. Would this be more effective to reject power supply noise, compared to just using the PIC's internal 5V as positive reference? The PIC is powered from the same power supply as the op-amp.

PIC16F1788 datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001675B.pdf

OP-amp AD8629ARZ datasheet: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8628_8629_8630.pdf

Voltage regulator LM340LAZ-5.0: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm140l.pdf